# Create a div that overlay all page and captures all events

Tags: javascript, events, dom

I want a div that overlay all page and I want that the div captures all events (in particular touch) then if a button is in the page the button must not be clickable.
I tried with:

```
background = document.createElement('div');
                background.style = `
                display:block;
                width:100%;
                height:100vh;
                position:fixed;
                top:0px;
                left:0px;
                z-index:9;
                background-color:black;
                opacity:0.3;`;
                document.body.appendChild(background);
```

and then

```
background.addEventListener('touchend', (e)=>{e.stopPropagation();}, true);
```

but it doesn't work. My page is in a cordova project.

Ok I've fixed, the problem was that in other portion of code I deleted the div before the div could manage the events.

Comment: ...aaaand what have you tried so far to accomplish this, and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/bv2oLrcs/

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<button>Click me if you can!</button>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#myDiv{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution but it doesn't work, my page is a page of a cordova project

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most elegant answer, but the first thing that comes to my head is create a div that wraps your entire page and then set its z-index to a really high number and its height 100% and width 100%

Something like this:

```
#overlay {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:1000;
}

<body>
<div id="overlay">

html content here!

</div>
</body>

<script>
$(document).on("click", "#overlay", function () {
    alert("overlay clicked")
});
```